# How to configure TLSv1.2 on Camel's http component to call an external service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jsse, camel-http

Below is the configured route I am using, to call an external service.

**services_routes.xml**

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


    <routeContext id="servicesCommonRoutes"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <route id="Route">
            <from uri="direct:route" />
            <marshal>
                <custom ref="Request" />
            </marshal>
            <setHeader name="Content-Type" inheritErrorHandler="true">
                <constant>application/json</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader name="CamelHttpMethod">
                <constant>POST</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="{{svrRouteEndpoint}}" />
            <unmarshal>
                <custom ref="Response" />
            </unmarshal>
        </route>

    </routeContext>
</beans>
```

**application.properties**

```
svrRouteEndpoint=https://vpce-somehost.awazonaws.com/endpoint
svrApiKey=0123abcd
```

**Service.java**

```
@Autowired
private ProducerTemplate template;
    
 @Value("${svrApiKey}")
private String svrApiKey;


public Response process(Request req, Map<String, Object> headers) throws CamelExecutionException {
    Response response = template.requestBodyAndHeaders("direct:route", req, headers, Response.class);
    return response;
}

 public Map<String, Object> createHeaders(String xWuExternalrefid) {
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("x-api-key", svrApiKey);
    return headers;
}
```

**Issue:**

Now using the above route when I try to access the service hosted on amazon-aws with the **vpce** URL provided. I am getting a Forbidden response code = "403" with {"message" : "Forbidden"}.

There are no other **headers** required to access the service except "**x-api-key**", so there is a possibility that somehow the **TLS version** is in not matching at client vs server side.

I need call the service with **producerTemplate**, but for that I need to configure/ensure **TLSv1.2** on Camel Client.

> So how to configure(xml) **TLSv1.2** on my routes in
> **service_routes.xml**(with minimum configuration), such that producerTemplate/camel client is able to access the service, and **enforce SSL to be TLSv1.2**.

Comment: Is the vpce URI successful when called from a browser/generic HTTP client? Have you [verified that the issue is related to a failing TLS handshake](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)? Have you read on how to [configure Camel's HTTP component for TLS](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/http-component.html#_setting_up_ssl_for_http_client) in case it is really related to TLS, which I'm not so sure about as there should be a connection issue and not some 403 Forbidden response in that regard IMO?

Comment: @RomanVottner, vpce URI is successful when using postmam/OKHttp client with the provided headers, but when it's being called from spring application using apache-camel then it's giving forbidden response 403, Which stated that there is a issue with client configuration